# iframe content not loading (no request fired)

Tags: html, iframe

I have a problem where the src of an iframe is not loaded, and I just can't find out why this is happening.

The piece of code in question:

```
<div style="margin-left:20%;margin-right:20%; width:60%; position: absolute; top: 450px"> 
<iframe id="frame" name="frame" marginwidth="0"  src="main.html" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="1000px"></iframe></div>
```

When loaded into the Tryit editor from W3schools, it works (404, but that's understandable), and using editor light for Chrome, it also works. But when run on the actual site (www.wolfeh.com), it just doesn't load. It doesn't even send out a request for main.html.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

**Update**

Was just too late with this, looks like someone put the old code back. Still not sure what it was, but the problem has been averted.

Comment: The frame loads up fine for me.

Comment: +1, loads fine in chrome, firefox, and IE9 here  (although IE9 had weird styling)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's going on on your side, but the frame loads ok. I would try adding the absolute path to it just in case:

```
<div style="margin-left:20%;margin-right:20%; width:60%; position: absolute; top: 450px"> 
<iframe id="frame" name="frame" marginwidth="0"  src="http://wolfeh.com/main.html" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="1000px"></iframe></div>
```